# Boot Problem: "Boot Loader; /casper/vmlinuz: read error @ 0"

Tags: boot, live-usb, bootloader

I have a SanDisk - Cruzer 16GB USB 2.0 Flash Drive - Black as my usb, I used the link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop to download Ubuntu 15.04 64-Bit and I used http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download to make my usb live. After I finished making the live usb I booted it up snd it showed the message:

```
Boot Loader; /casper/vmlinuz: read error @ 0
```

can anyone help me I have been trying to find a way to fix it for about a month so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Open your USB drive and see you have indeed a file names `vmlinuz` inside a directory named `casper` (see the image below).

[image]
If not something must have gone wrong during the creation of live USB. There is another user who faced the same problem using the same tool you used to create live USB. See [/casper/vmlinuz: not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257078/casper-vmlinuz-not-found)

As suggested in an answer in the above post, you can also try adding the `.efi` extension to `vmlinuz` (or remove if `efi` is already there) and then try to boot.

If this also did not work, perhaps you should try other tools such as [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

If your downloaded ISO is not corrupted and your creation of bootable USB has worked out well, you should end up with a USB having following folders (example shown here is 15.04):

[image]

Comment: When I load my usb from the BIOS it shows me this ![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ksskL_j4sPLXJCVmtPbGZ1aWc&authuser=0) and when I try to open the usb file ![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ksskL_j4sPZzVHVEc4VW5vRkU&authuser=0) it is somehow empty and here is a picture to show you ![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ksskL_j4sPX1NQeFNWazRoOG8&authuser=0) is there anyway you could help me with my problem please tell me @Ron