# Macpro Refind Ubuntu installation error

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, refit, refind

Please someone HELP I have a problem. I am trying to install ubuntu on a macpro6,1  version 10.10.4 running OS X Yosemite. I am trying to install ubtuntu using reFind. The main issue is that when ever i boot EFI and try either the, try ubuntu or install ubuntu option, with or without nomodeset added, i get the following error message:

Booting a command list

```
error: file `/casper/vmlinuz.efi' not found
unaligned pointer 0xa5a5a5a5
Aborted. press any key to exit.
```

I would appreciate your support, if you can lend me ur skills on how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Somebody has voted to close because you specified "version 10.10.4," which, if that's an Ubuntu version, is very old. Please clarify whether that's an Ubuntu version number or an OS X version number. Beyond that, I recommend you check your installation medium for errors, and maybe try a different medium type, if possible (switch from CD-R to USB flash drive or vice-versa).

Comment: The question tags specify 14.04 and 14.10, so I am pretty positive that it is the OS X version number (Yosemite is 10.10)

Answer (score 0):

Check the usb-drive/dvd for the file `/casper/vmlinuz`. Sometimes it has the extension `.efi`, sometimes not. If the error specifies a missing .efi at the end, add it.

Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257078/casper-vmlinuz-not-found) thread can help.